# Dictionary Creation Fails When Created From URL Encoded JSON In Xcode 15

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xcode15

```
let json = "%22%7B%5C%22key%5C%22%3A%5C%22value%5C%22%7D%22"
let data = json.data(using: .utf8)
if let data = data {
    let dict = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data)
    print(dict)
}
```

This used to work in Xcode 14.2 but since we updated to Xcode 15, fails with

```
"JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set. around line 1, column 0."
```

This happens on `let dict = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data)` but I haven't managed to find notes of anything changing with regards to the dictionary initialization. Has anyone run into this?

Comment: It's percent escaped, do you still want the `%22`? And it has been stringified as the double quotes are escaped.

Comment: That's isn't JSON, it's URL-encoded JSON (`"{\"key\":\"value\"}"`).  URL-decode it first.

Comment: I am aware that it isn't plain JSON, it's URL encoded. My point was that the above code worked fine before Xcode 15 and not it doesn't. So previously the serialization could handle it being encoded (I guess?) but now not?

Comment: I don't see how it could have worked before.  URL-decode it and move on.

Comment: Could the changes to url encoding be relevant here, https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/url/3126806-init

Comment: It shouldn't have worked before, ie your code as such. Percent Escaping step is missing. Then, it's JSON Stringified, and I don't recall the `.allowFramgents` being set to true, nor doing the step itself. I think there have been a change in the encoding process that make then the decoding process different...

Answer (score 0):

This works, but there are some questions about your data:

```
let json = "%22%7B%5C%22key%5C%22%3A%5C%22value%5C%22%7D%22"
//You need first to convert "%22" into """ and so on.
let percentEscaped = json.removingPercentEncoding
// The force unwrap as the normal output might show to many escape for debugging purposes
print(percentEscaped)    // Optional("\"{\\\"key\\\":\\\"value\\\"}\"")
print(percentEscaped!).  // "{\"key\":\"value\"}"
let data = percentEscaped?.data(using: .utf8)
if let data = data {
    do {
        //Now the JSON is a String, it's JSON Stringified, so we need to get the String first.
        let strJSON = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .fragmentsAllowed) as! String
        print("strJSON: \(strJSON)") //Because JSON was Stringified
        let dict = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: Data(strJSON.utf8))
        print(dict)
    }
    catch {
        print("error: \(error)")
    }
}
```

Final output:

```
{
    key = value;
}
```

Question:
Why is the JSON Stringified at first place? It shouldn't need the first and last "%22" for instance, etc.